# How to filter and show data in table view swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'am trying to filter the array and add the filtered values in new array and show them in table view..

```html
var names = [String]()
names = ["Name","Student","Roll No"]

    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            print("start changes")
            
            if names.contains(where: {$0 == txtSearch.text})
            {
                tblRestaurantData.reloadData()
            } else {
               //item could not be found
            }
```

i've written the above code but i am confused how to get and display the filtered values in tableview ?

Comment: You're not modifying the array that is used for the table view, so... Nothing happens when you call `reloadData()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if !names.contains(textField.text ?? "") {
        names.append(textField.text ?? "")
        tblRestaurantData.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
   let resultArray = names.filter({ (value) -> Bool in
        if value.contains(txtSearch.text) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    })
}
```